# Attempting to edit the tag guidance for stellar-core gives a 404 error

Tags: discussion, editing, tagging

The tag [stellar-core](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-core) currently has no tag wiki guidance.

With most tags, when clicking on "can you help us create it"...

[image: Snip of https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-core]

...the tag editing screen appears.

However, with this tag, the tag info page appears instead...
[image: Snip of https://stellar.stackexchange.com/tags/stellar-core/info]

If you try to go directly to the edit page - [stellar-core](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-core) is tag number 32 on the site so the URL https://stellar.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/32 should take you directly to the edit - instead you get a 404 error.

Trying other tags directly by number does work, without trying every single tag, I only see the error on this one.

Update: Given the answer, I've removed [bug](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [pending edit](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/183) on the [stellar-core](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-core) tag excerpt which must be reviewed before you can edit further. If you look carefully [at the tag info page](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/tags/stellar-core/info), you can see:

> **edit pending**    history   excerpt history

This isn't particularly obvious unless you're looking for it, mind you, but I suspect this is the reason.

Hence, this does not seem to be a bug, and the excerpt just needs to be reviewed before you can do anything.

A 404 error here doesn't seem right for the actual problem in this case (a more informative status code would be helpful), but I suppose since that URL isn't linked to if there is an edit pending, it's not too important.

Comment: Good spot, I missed the edit pending.  I would agree something better than a 404 page would be a good idea to prevent this confusion again.